# Rails scope that orders Users by a Reputation Score

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, filtering

I have a users table and I keep a reputation score on each user.  The reputation score is the combined score from 2 factors:

1. total followers on the Users projects (projects he/she created)
2. total votes on the Users tasks (tasks that he/she created)

My goal is to allow users to filter users by most recent (the standard index action) or by users with the most reputation.  What Rails scope would give back the list of Users ordered by this 'total reputation score' in order of highest score to lowest?  thx,

My code is as follows:

User.RB Model

```
def total_reputation_score
  project_follower_count + task_vote_count
end

scope :by_reputation, -> { #HOW DO I CREATE THIS SCOPE? }
```

Users Controller

```
def index
  @users = User.text_search(params[:query]).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 12)
end

  def most_reputation
    @users = policy_scope(User)
    @users = @users.
      text_search(params[:query]).
      by_reputation.
      paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 12)

    render :index
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you *can* do this in SQL on the fly, you really want to:

Add a [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) for each of the two count items shown here; this adds these as calculated columns that Rails will maintain for you, then do this for your scope:

```
User.order(User.arel_table[:project_follower_count] + User.arel_table[:task_vote_count]).reverse_order
```

(or something similar)

Alternately you can double down on your RDBMS and build out indices to handle on the fly.

Comment: thanks corey - so just to make sure i'm understanding... its just a matter of adding a new integer field on the Users table for project_follower_count and  also for task_vote_count.  Then once I have those I can just do:   scope :by_reputation, -> { User.order(User.arel_table[:project_follower_count] + User.arel_table[:task_vote_count).reverse_order }

Comment: is that correct, or do i not even need the scope any longer?

Comment: Also i read here (and a couple other places) that counter caches are not good for many to many relationships.  My follower and vote counts, etc are all linked up by has_many -> through relationships. Can you do counter cache with many to many?      https://coderwall.com/p/muvy9w/forget-counter-cache-for-many-to-many-associations-in-rails

Comment: @BB500 I would use a scope, yes. You also need to set up the counter cache. On mobile now, but you can google to find the docs/examples.

Comment: @BB500 Why would a task vote be has_many? Seems like a belongs_to relationship to me. Not sure on "project followers", depends on the architecture.

Comment: well i've got some crazy relationships setup.  users have 'own_tasks' via the task model.  Tasks have taskrelationships where the actual voting takes place (its a vote on a relationship between the task and a separate model).  I'll take a stab at the counter cache and maybe that's a subject for another stackO question.  You've answered my question on this one.  thx

Comment: @BB500 Gotcha; in general, messy architecture causes a ton of downstream work. Might be worth the time to revise and simplify if you can afford it. The more you can rely on built-in functionality the less you have to test or maintain!